# Blow up along a valuation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory, blowup

What does it mean to blow up along a valuation? Under what circumstances do we usually blow up along a valuation?

I am having trouble finding a precise definition, so any references or examples would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In which context did you see it?

Comment: I came across this in a paper. A (partial) result that I saw was : Suppose $K \longrightarrow K^*$ is a finite extension of algebraic function fields over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$, $\nu^*$ is a $k$-valuation of $K^*$, with restriction $\nu$ to $K$, and $R \longrightarrow S$ is an inclusion of algebraic regular local rings of $K$ and $K^*$, such that $\nu^*$ dominates $S$, and $S$ dominates $R$. Then $\exists R \longrightarrow R_1$ and $S \longrightarrow S_1$, such that the horizontal arrows are products of blowups of nonsingular subschemes along the valuation $\nu*$.

Comment: I do not know that particular result. But this is something one can do. Let $R, k,K, \nu$ be as in your comment. I would like to assume that $k \subset R$ and $K$ is the field of fractions of $R$. Let $m$ be the maximal ideal of $R$. Consider the blowup $\pi : Bl_{V(m)}(R) \to R$. Since $\pi$ is proper, the valuation $\nu$ has center on $Bl_{V{m}}(R)$. Let $R_1$ denote the local ring dominated by (the center of) $\nu$ on $Bl_{V{m}}(R)$. This is also regular. You can do this inductively. I “believe” that you can make such arragement so that $R, S$ behave as in your comment.